# Xcode: compile without running

Tags: c++, xcode, build

Xcode has a 'play button' to build and then run the current scheme for C++ code. Is there a way to *only build* the program *without running* it in Xcode?

Answer (score 12):

Press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or choose "Build" from Xcode's "Product" menu.